# How can I skip the rest of a script without exiting the invoking shell, when sourcing the script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, exit, source-command

I have a bash script, where I call `exit` somewhere to skip the rest of the script when `getopts` doesn't recognize an option or doesn't find an expected option argument.

```
while getopts ":t:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        t)
            timelen="$OPTARG"
            ;;
        \?) printf "illegal option: -%s\n" "$OPTARG" >&2
            echo "$usage" >&2
            exit 1
            ;;
        :) printf "missing argument for -%s\n" "$OPTARG" >&2
           echo "$usage" >&2
           exit 1
           ;;
    esac
done

# reset of the script
```

I `source` the script in a bash shell. When something is wrong, the shell exits.

Is there some way other than `exit` to skip the rest of the script but without exiting the invoking shell?

Replacing `exit` with `return` doesn't work like for a function call, and the rest of the script will runs.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm?  `return` seems to work for me.  If I have a script `echo hello ; return ; echo there` then source it I only get the `hello` output.

Comment: Thanks, @StephenHarris  I made a mistake. I use `exit` inside a while loop. I guess replacing it with `return` only exits the while loop, but continue to run the rest of the program after the while loop. How can I skip the rest of the program  then?

Comment: @Tim `break` exits a loop, `return` exits a function or a sourced script.

Comment: @Tim, why do you source it instead of executing it?

Comment: Additional details: [How can I tell whether my script was sourced (dotted in) or executed?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/109)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `return`.

The return bash builtin will exit the sourced script without stopping the calling (parent/sourcing) script.

From man bash:

> return [n]
>   Causes a function to stop executing and return the value specified by n to its caller. If n is omitted, the return status is that of the last command executed in the function body. … **If return is used outside a function, but during execution of a script by the . (source) command, it causes the shell to stop executing that script and return either n or the exit status of the last command executed within the script as the exit status of the script.** …

Comment: Thanks. Do `return [n]` and `exit n` work the same except in a function or a script being sourced?

Comment: No, a return is never an exit. An exit will "get out" of the running script (shell). A return will stop reading (and executing) either a sourced file or a function. A return outside a function and outside a sourced file will be reported as an error by bash. An exit (almost) never will be an error and will "stop all processing". @Tim

Answer (score 6):

You could simply wrap your script in a function and then use `return` the way you describe.

```
#!/bin/bash
main () {
    # Start of script
    if [ <condition> ]; then
        return
    fi
    # Rest of the script will not run if returned
}

main "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

[`return` exits sourced scripts (and functions)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#return).

In your case:

```
while getopts ":t:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        t)
            timelen="$OPTARG"
            ;;
        \?) printf "illegal option: -%s\n" "$OPTARG" >&2
            echo "$usage" >&2
            return 1
            ;;
        :) printf "missing argument for -%s\n" "$OPTARG" >&2
           echo "$usage" >&2
           return 1
           ;;
    esac
done
```

Example test:

```
$ cat script1.sh
echo script1
source ./script2.sh
echo script1 ends
```

```
$ cat script2.sh
echo script2

while true; do
    return
done

echo script2 ends
```

```
$ bash script1.sh
script1
script2
script1 ends
```

Also sourcing `script2.sh` directly does the correct thing (without exiting from the current shell session):

```
$ source script2.sh
script2
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases I will want to allow exit except if I'm at the first shell, so I use this:

```
if [[ $SHLVL -gt 1 ]]; then exit 0; fi
```